# Why is my game still picking up google play services?

Tags: google-play-services

I am using Google Play services in my game. I messed up with my keystore, and had to sign it all over again. I deleted the project in Google Play Services as well as Google APIS, but I still have access to the achievements, even though I changed the app ID in my manifest. What is going on?! I just want to create a new Google Play Services server for my game which has the right signature.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project and do a full rebuild? did you remove the old APK from your phone and do a new install? sometimes old code is cached.

Comment: which part helped so I can write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do are this things:

- Clean your project
- Do a full rebuild
- Remove old APK from your test device
- Install the last APK